# Suspend and Resume Lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I need something to suspend Lambdas in C++ and resume them. I try to narrow it down to a very simple example:

Lets assume I have a singleton class `orchestrator` where I can register a lambda:

```
int main() {

    orchestrator::getInstance().registerLambda([&](){
        // Do something:
        ...
        wait(); // Suspend here
        // When waked up continue here:
        ...
        wait(); // Suspend here
        ...
    });

    orchestrator::start()
}
```

In the `orchestrator` class itself there is a main loop which calls then this lambda-function from time to time.

```
orchestrator::start()
{
    while(true) {
        lambda();
        // Do other stuff:
        ...
    }
}
```

I thought about co-routines but they seam to complex in my opinion. The solution should stick with the concept of lambda and standard C++. Modern C++ like '11, '17 or '20 would also be fine.

Comment: This is precisely what coroutines are for. The complex part is defining the return type, which you don't have to do if you use a library that already has one.

Comment: Yeah I'm also think in this direction. But would that also work with a lambda?

Comment: Yes it works thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of the future where coroutine support will be more complete, here's one way a coroutine could look:

```
resumable foo() {
    std::cout << "Starting foo\n";

    while (true) {
        co_await std::suspend_always{}; // Could be co_await wait(); if you prefer, if wait() returns suspend_always
        std::cout << "Resuming foo\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    auto m = foo();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Back in main to resume foo\n";
        m();
    }

    std::cout << "Done main\n";
}
```

This outputs "Starting foo", followed by 5 back-and-forths between `main` and `foo`, and then "Done main". Using a lambda is trivial: specify `resumable` as the return type. ([See the live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o46hs34de))

The messy part is defining `resumable`, and this part belongs in a library. I'd say it's a good candidate for the standard library in some form after some more common types like `task` and `generator`. In fact, this type is basically a `generator<void>` with a different iteration API. Without using a library, it's not *too* bad, but note that I haven't bothered to do things like define what happens if you try to resume the lambda after it's done:

```
class resumable {
    std::coroutine_handle<> _coro;

    explicit resumable(std::coroutine_handle<> h) noexcept
      : _coro(h) {}

public:
    // All fluff except for giving resumable a coroutine handle
    struct promise_type {
        resumable get_return_object() noexcept { return resumable(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)); }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() noexcept {}
        void unhandled_exception() noexcept {}
    };

    // This is how the caller interacts, they just call this object repeatedly.
    void operator()() const noexcept {
        _coro.resume();
    }
};
```

If not using coroutines, it's back to good old state machines:

```
struct state_resumable {
    // TODO: Store all state

    state_resumable() {
        std::cout << "Starting resumable\n";
    }

    void operator()() {
        // TODO: Figure out what to execute next based on the stored state
        std::cout << "Resuming resumable\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto m = state_resumable();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Back in main to resume resumable\n";
        m();
    }

    std::cout << "Done main\n";
}
```

What isn't shown here is the effort required to manually keep track of state. Coroutines automatically store away the local variables in your function and restore them when the coroutine is resumed, plus keep track of which part of the function to execute next. With a state machine, you have to do all of these yourself. You cannot use a single lambda as above because only coroutines can actually suspend mid-execution. With a state machine, you're pretending to do this, but the function must actually finish completely each time.

Comment: yes it works like this! What would be the return type of wait()?

Comment: Ah found it: 

```std::experimental::suspend_always wait(...) {...}```

Comment: @Matthias, Yes, it's just an ordinary refactoring of moving the temporary to a named function. The other option you might expect would be `void wait() { co_await std::experimental::suspend_always{}; }`. However, this won't work because C++ coroutines are stackless (they keep track of the stack frame instead of keeping an entire stack). Hence, every suspension point in the lambda must be explicit.

Comment: okay, that would have been my next question. for better readability it would have been nice to bring the co_await into the wait() function. Maybe I could reach this with a macro instead ;-)

Comment: You certainly could use a simple `#define WAIT() co_await std::experimental::suspend_always{}`. Macros aren't great, but it is straightforward. The real disadvantage of being able to suspend the outermost coroutine from within an inner one comes when you have many coroutines active at once. A stack per coroutine is a lot of overhead when you start getting millions or billions of them. However, they do tend to be more intuitive and do have their own place besides, so C++ could potentially get those too later.

Comment: Is it possible to identify in the ```wait(...){...}``` from which co-routine it was called?

Comment: Not in general, no. What you can do is have `wait()` return a custom awaiter type that can have extra logic in `await_suspend` where the handle is directly available. There's an example of using this to schedule the resumption on a new thread on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), but the logic can be whatever as long as it fits into that scaffolding. It can seem a bit arbitrary without really understanding how coroutines work, but it all has reasons. Keep in mind that we're already in "expert territory" here by defining these types.

Comment: Yes also this works, thank you so much for explaining me all this in such a detail. With this knowledge, I wrote a small discrete event simulator, if you are interested you can check it out here: https://github.com/myzinsky/des/tree/7bd29984f75e404f8ed1420187ced309ae4787f5/sw

Comment: @Matthias, Neat. If it helps, you can compare yours to [another one](https://github.com/fschuetz04/simcpp20) that I remember seeing pop up recently on reddit. I imagine the comparison will prove interesting.